# Evaluating $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k-1}$ is a convergent series.

Is there some way to evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k-1}$

This does not look like arithmetic or geometric series to me.

Please help

Comment: The series in question is divergent.

Comment: Who says it's convergent

Comment: You have $1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}+\dots$.  Now... compare this to $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}+\dots$.  Which is bigger?  Your original? (*1 is bigger than 1/2, and 1/3 is bigger than 1/4 etc...*)  All right.  Now, let's factor $\frac{1}{2}$ out of every term of the second... we have $\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots\right)$.  Do you recognize this series in the parentheses?  You should.  "*This does not look like arithmetic or geometric series to me*"  because it isn't either of those.  It is *harmonic*.

Comment: Technically, your original with the way you have it written with $k$ starting at zero (*rather than starting with $k=1$*) and subtracting, your series is $-1 + 1 + \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\dots$, but when talking about convergence or divergence, we only really care about tail end behavior.  We can remove however many terms at the beginning to make things convenient for ourselves and worry about them after the fact.  I left the $-1$ out of the previous comment because I didn't want to have to deal with division by zero errors in my proposed comparison.

Comment: Maybe you missed a $(-1)^k$ in the summands?

Comment: It is harmonic because the denominator is linear and hence in AP

Comment: $\frac{1}{2k-1} > \frac{1}{2k}$, $k>1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My Solution:**

Notice that $f(x)=\frac{1}{2x-1}$ monotonically decreases in $[1,+\infty)$.

Then $\forall k>0$, we have

$$
\frac{1}{2k-1}>\int_k^{k+1}\frac{1}{2x-1}dx,
$$

and

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}>\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_k^{k+1}\frac{1}{2x-1}dx=\int_1^{n+1}\frac{1}{2x-1}dx=\frac{1}{2}ln(2n+1),
$$

*i.e.*,

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}>\frac{1}{2}ln(2n+1)-1.
$$

Since

$$
\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\text{lim}}\left[\frac{1}{2}ln(2n+1)-1\right]=+\infty,
$$

the original series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k-1}$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

We know that for any $k \in \mathbb{W}$

$$-1<2$$
$$2k-1 < 2k + 2 $$

On cross multiplication,

$$\frac{1}{2k+2} < \frac{1}{2k-1} $$
$$\implies \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2k+2} < \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2k-1} $$

The RHS in the above inequality is convergent if and only if the LHS is convergent. If LHS $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2k+2}$ is convergent then

$$\implies \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2(k+1)} \text{ is also convergent}$$
$$\implies \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{k+1} \text{ is also convergent}$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1} \text{ is also convergent}$$
$$\implies \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1} \text{ is also convergent}$$
If we put $m=k+1$
$$\implies \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m} \text{ is also convergent}$$

But this is just the harmonic series which we know is divergent. There you go. A contradiction, which arises because of our assumption that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2k-1}$ is convergent.

Therefore $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2k-1}$ is divergent.